# Nesting instead of expression

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have two lines of script:

```
IIF (name.value ='no',  name1.value, name2.Value) as [name 1],


IIF (name.value ='yes', name3.value, name4.value) as [name 1.5],
```

which gives me an output that once in SSRS I combine into one field in a table by using this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!name_1.Value is nothing, Fields!name_1_5.Value, Fields!name_1.Value)
```

However, instead of using this fairly clumsy expression I'd like to rewrite the T-SQL above to bring the data through there, rather than muddle around in SSRS. Is there a way the two lines of script above can be nested to give me the same output I achieve via the expression in SSRS?

Any help gratefully received.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to return the first non-null value, like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        IIF (name.value ='no',  name1.value, name2.Value),
        IIF (name.value ='yes', name3.value, name4.value)
    ) as [name 1 or 1.5]
FROM MyTable
```